# Why compilers give different warning message for auto x = a; and auto x(a);?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, g++

The code is simple:

```
class AAA {};
AAA a;

int main() {
    AAA x = a;
    AAA y(a);
}
```

For g++4.8 with `-std=c++11 -Wall`, it gives warning only for the first line:

> warning: variable 'x' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]

For vc12 with `/Za /W3`, it gives warning only for the second line:

> warning C4101: 'y' : unreferenced local variable

Why are the compilers treating the code differently?  It seems that g++ considers `y` as **used** and vc considers `x` as **used**.  What's the compilers' logic behind that?

EDIT: As far as I tested, the order and number of variables involved doesn't matter. What matters only is the form of initialization (copy-initialization vs. direct-initialization). I asked the question in case there is something I don't know about the difference between these two forms of initialization that is reflected by the compilers' behavior (the difference I know of is implicit vs. explicit copy constructor call). Compilers do have lots of freedom on emitting warnings, but bottom line they have their meaningful and self-consistent logic, right?

Comment: [Clang wins.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/641b27e2c3ef2cc8)

Comment: The second form is instantiating an instance of the class.  The first is only assigning an instance.

Comment: @HotLicks  I think both call copy ctor to initialize the object, except the difference that the first is implicit call (copy-init) and the second is explicit call (direct-init).  I don't know what you mean by `assigning` vs. `instantiating`.

Comment: I have submitted a [GCC bugreport](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60212).

Answer (score 3):

At /W4, Visual C++ 2013 reports:

```
x.cpp(6) : warning C4101: 'y' : unreferenced local variable
x.cpp(5) : warning C4189: 'x' : local variable is initialized but not referenced
```

When using Visual C++, always compile at /W4 (and optionally turn on additional warnings you care about).  The difference in warning levels for these two warnings is likely due to historical reasons (e.g., C4109 was added later, and was given a higher warning level to avoid introducing new warnings into legacy code during toolchain updates).

Comment: Thank you very much.  This totally explains the case for vc.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ standard only requires diagnostics for certain errors, and doesn't differentiate between "error" and "warning" dignostics. As far as the formaleese is concerned, not blinking a light on the keyboard can be a dignostic. So there's immense freedom for the compilers, and as with much else in C++ compilers are forced by the market, not by the standard.

Different compilers differ in what kinds of warnings they can emit, the meaning of commaon options (in particular "all" warnings), and how they arbitrarily choose what to warn about and not.

You can experiment to test various hypotheses about a given compiler, if you're really interested in this. For example, removing the variable that's warned about, does that make the compiler warn about the other? What about three unused variables, do you then get warning for one, two or three? Does the order of declarations matter? And so on.

Comment: As far as I tested, the order and number of variables involved doesn't matter.  What matters only is the form of initialization (direct-init vs. copy-init).  I asked the question in case there is something I don't know about the difference between these two forms of initialization that is reflected by the compiler behavior (the difference I know of is explicit vs. implicit copy ctor call).  Compilers do have lots of freedom on emitting warnings, but bottom line they have their meaningful and self-consistent logic, right?

Comment: "meaningful and selc-consistent logic", well, not always. :) but lest i get a horde of angry compiler-X enthusiasts excited, i better not give concrete examples. anyway, as i recall from old days, with g++ you had to specify at least some level of optimziation (e.g. just `-O`) in order to activate the analysis that let it report unused variables, maybe worth trying if you haven't.